# Sed find and replace a commented line with spaces for Ubuntu unattended/automatic reboots

Tags: bash, shell

I have a line in Ubuntu's unattended upgrade file, `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades`, that I'm trying to swap out entirely from this:

```
// Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot false;
```

to this:

```
Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot true;
```

If I echo the line like this, it works:

```
echo "// Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot false;" | sed 's#// Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot false;#Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot true;#'
```

However, if I try the same command in-place with the file, it fails:

```
sed -i.bak 's#// Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot false;#Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot true;#' /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades
```

Sample data for testing on a file:

```
// Automatically reboot *WITHOUT CONFIRMATION*
//  if the file /var/run/reboot-required is found after the upgrade
// Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot "false";
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: @Inian I'm not seeing any errors

Comment: Even if that's the only line in my file, it fails, and yes, clearly I checked the resulting file before posting a question to SO. I included some more sample data for you to test, but if you're not testing on Ubuntu, your sed may be different than Ubuntu's.

Comment: are you saying that the sed commands out put not reflect in file 50unattended-upgrades?

Comment: @AbhijitPritam Correct, as you can see, I wrote an in-place sed command to replace the contents of the file and create backup with .bak. The command failed to replace the contents of the original file.

Comment: I have provided you a solution.

Comment: I think there is no mystery but a simple bug in your writing. In the file the syntax is: `"false"`, in your sed command line you wrote the syntax `false`. On the other hand in your echo command you forgot the `""`, so it worked.

Comment: @ArnoBozo Oh holy crap, thank you. I'm an idiot.

Answer (score 1):

This was me being an idiot, as @ArnoBozo helpfully pointed out.

My echo example lacked quotes in the "false" and "true", whereas the file itself has quotes around "false".

I'm not sure if I should delete this question or not, as it's so clearly a dumb mistake.

Comment: Indeed you could delete the question as it will provide no help to others. Yet you are not an idiot, it is a common way of "building" a bug. Hopefully I did not waste much time; I used the commands and samples you provided. They were pertinent, I did not reproduced the bug so I could quickly see the problem.

Comment: @ArnoBozo looks like I can't delete it as it already has answers. Oh well! Thanks for pointing out the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

To reflect the changes in your file you have to do the following, First redirect the output to a temp file and rename it to the original file. This is working for me.

```
sed 's/\/\/ Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot false/Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot true/g' > /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/tmp.dat

mv /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/tmp.dat  /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades
```

Comment: This shouldn't require two lines, sed -i should replace the contents in-place. Further, this doesn't work. Did you test this in Ubuntu?